# Displaying uidatepicker on the left of table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, datetimepicker

I am displaying UIDatePicker on tableview cell and there are no other elements on that cell. However whenever I open the app, I always see date picker on right side of the view. How do I display it on the left? I tried below 2 solutions, but it didn't work for me.

```
dateTimePicker.frame(forAlignmentRect: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: dateTimePicker.frame.width, height: dateTimePicker.frame.height))
dateTimePicker.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

***My date picker code:***

```
class EditCheckInDatePicker: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTimePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    func formatCell(cell: EditCheckInDatePicker, checkInDate: Date) {
        dateTimePicker.date = checkInDate
        dateTimePicker.minuteInterval = 30
        dateTimePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        dateTimePicker.minimumDate = Date().nearest30Mins()
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            dateTimePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
        }
        dateTimePicker.frame(forAlignmentRect: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: dateTimePicker.frame.width, height: dateTimePicker.frame.height))
        dateTimePicker.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
     }
}
```

***This is what I always see. I want date time picker on left:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `frame(forAlignmentRect:` does not set the frame for the view you are calling it on - rather it returns the view's frame for the `CGRect` you pass in.

Next, since you are clearly building your UI in Storyboards or xibs, why not just set the layout attributes in there?  You should be able to easily constrain your picker to the left side of the superview.  If you prefer to build your UI programmatically you should remove it from the xib and instantiate and add to the superview manually, and then you should look into how to use [NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor) to lay out your views.